# Cannot write more than two fields, using SPServices UpdateListItems

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I'm creating list items in a SharePoint (MOSS) list programmatically. I've been successful with several different techniques, as long as I limit the number of fields to two. I need to provide 76 field values, actually. Am trying SPServices UpdateListItems method. Latest versions of jQuery (1.7.1) and SPServices (0.7.0).

My first approach was to use the valuepairs option. I have two arrays I can use to feed this. Worked fine for two values. I then tried statically filling variables and using those. Same result. Switched to the CAML Batch method. Same result.

The complete function status is always "Success." Nothing gets written to the list.

```
var batch = "<Batch OnError='Continue'><Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>";
batch += "<Field Name='" + varTitle + "'>" + varTitle_val + "</Field>";
batch += "<Field Name='" + varformid + "'>" + varformid_val + "</Field>";
batch += "<Field Name='" + varee1 + "'>Hi!</Field>";
batch += "<Field Name='" + varee2 + "'>there</Field>";
batch += "<Field Name='" + varee3 + "'>how</Field>";
batch += "<Field Name='" + varee4 + "'>are</Field>";
batch += "</Method></Batch>";
$().SPServices({
  operation: "UpdateListItems",
  batchCmd: "New",
  listName: "CRMSAccessRequest",
// valuepairs: [[arFields[0],arValues[0]],[arFields[1],arValues[1]],[arFields  [2],arValues[2]]],  //fails with more than two fields
// valuepairs: [[varTitle,varTitle_val],[varformid,arValues[1]],[varee1,varee1_val],[varee2,varee2_val]],  // ditto
  updates: batch,      
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
    alert("status of write attempt: " + Status);
 }
}); //SPServices
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Success" you are getting back just tells you that there was a successful transaction. You need to look at the returned XML to see what issues there might be.

The easiest way:
alert(xData.responseText);

My guess is that one or more of your field names is incorrect. It's hard to tell since you are using variables for the column names.

Comment: Will investigate, thank you. I just wrote multiple fields to a different list using pure Ajax, so I know it can be done!

Comment: Fascinating. Field names are simple (ee1, ee2) but I get this error: "One or more field types are not installed properly" Then checked internal names, and 'ee1' is being rendered as '_e_e1', etc. Using those names has not yet helped but at least I see where the difficulty is. I don't recall this particular modification of column names from your book!

Comment: This is important. Subsequent tests showed that such field names as "ee1" can never be used. I suspect that it is the use of the digit at the end, which conflicts somehow with the internal renaming system SP uses. Having such columns always generates the "field types not installed properly" error. Deleting the columns and replacing with, say, "eform_a" yielded expected success.

Comment: You need to use the InternalName for the columns. Here's a [blog post][1] of mine that may help you with it.


  [1]: http://sympmarc.com/2009/12/11/staticname-versus-displayname-on-sharepoint-lists/

Comment: OK, here was my mistake. SP renamed this field from 'ee1' to '%5Fx0065%5Fe1'. When I saw that, I first tried writing to '%5Fx0065%5Fe1'. The "bad field type" error occurred. Then, I tried writing to '_e_e1'. That failed for the same reason. The key is understanding that the proper internal name is: '_x0065_e1'. That worked.